# Numerical differentiation proof of convergence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Im learning Numerical methods and stumbled upon this exercise.
Prove that $f^{(k)}(x_0) = \frac{1}{h^k}\sum\limits_{j=-l}^rb_jf(x_0 +jh)+R_h(f)$ converges if and only if $\chi(z)=z^{-l}(z-1)^kQ(z)$, where Q(z) is a polynomial and Q(1) = 1. The $\chi(z)$ is the characteristic function and $\sum\limits_{j=-l}^rb_j = 0$.

What I got is that the characteristic function for the $f^{k}(x_0)$ is $\chi(z) = \sum\limits_{j=-l}^rb_jz^j$ and with some manipulation i can get $\chi(z) = z^{-l}(b_{-l}+b_{-l+1}z + b_{-l+2}z^2+...+b_{-1}z^{-1}+b_0+b_1z^+...+b_rz^r)$. If I assume that the $b_j$ corresponds to the Pascals triangle I can get $\chi(z)=z^{-l}(z-1)^k$, but this is a bold assumption and i still dont have the Q(z) anywhere.

Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong ?

Is it logical that $(z-1)^k * Q(z) = b_{-l}+b_{-l+1}z + b_{-l+2}z^2+...+b_{-1}z^{-1}+b_0+b_1z^+...+b_rz^r$ ?

Comment: Where did you stumble upon this exercise?

Comment: Somekind of lecture material or something. Its original text is in my native tongue so i had to translate it.